# Only need snap scroll trigger / simulate swipe gesture on mouse + trackpad

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project with 100% width & height panels and wanna make custom animations to transition between them.

Those transitions should be triggered by vertical swipes on **both touch and mouse devices** – I know mouses / trackpads don't support swipes, that's where the desired plugin comes into place.

`Onepage scroll` and `fullPage.js` handle scroll exactly how I need it, but come with a lot of other things I can't have.

So I'm looking for a plugin that only handles the swipe part or a **robust way** to handle the swipe-trigger myself.

Important requirement: There will be lightboxes on mobile which should scroll naturally. So I need a on / off toggle for these gestures. If I code them myself this will be easy. Tackle inside an existing plugin won't be–

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/
http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/purejs_onepage_scroll_demo.html

Thanks

---

**EDIT for Alvaros Answer**

`lethargy.js` seems promising, but I just can't get it to work oO (or completely misunderstand what is supposed to happen)

I have a blank page and just copied the code from the example of it's Github page with the default options.

```
var lethargy = new Lethargy();

$(window).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll wheel MozMousePixelScroll', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    e.stopPropagation();
    if(lethargy.check(e) !== false) {
        console.log(lethargy.check(e));
    }
});
```

Strangely I get the following log while switching between swipe up and down:

[image: False shouldnt even be there?]

As of my understanding there should only be `-1` and `1` per swipe. No `false` and not multiple `1`s or `-1`s on a single swipe. But that's what's happening.

Comment: Not quite sure why you can't use any of those libraries. What do you mean with " come with a lot of other things I can't have" ? What exactly is that?

Comment: I don't want the effect that comes with this plugin; I don't want the page to scroll at all; I don't want to be forced to use their html markup– I really do only need the trigger for the scroll so I can write my own callbacks into it etc.

Comment: I guess I could do it myself with `mousewheel` and `DOMMouseScroll` event etc.; but there are so many details and cross-browser issues to get right..

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try making it yourself the two biggest issues you are going to face are:

1 - Kinetic scrolling of laptops and some mouses such as the Apple mouse.

2- Touch devices.

So, you could use fullPage.js with empty sections and your own fixed elements that you animate using callbacks or the fullPage.js state classes. As seen [in this site](http://www.electricenjin.com/) or [this other one](https://sharp.vn/vn/cong-nghe-long-giat-khong-lo/). Both using fullPage.js.

Another option is using something like [lethargy.js](https://github.com/d4nyll/lethargy) which tries to solve the issue with kinetic scrolling. Although it doesn't deal with touch devices.

## Update

If you read [lethargy.js docs](https://github.com/d4nyll/lethargy) you'll see what those values mean:

> lethargy.check(e) will return 1 if it is a normal scroll up event, -1 if it is a normal scroll down event, and false if it is initiated by inertial scrolling.

So, a result of  `false` shows a kinetic scrolling which you do not want to work with. 
You only have to care about `1` and `-1` and that's all.

Comment: Okay, but if I use `fullPage.js` how would you solve that there will be overlays which should scroll naturally? I need functionality to toggle the scroll event on and off.

Comment: Not quite sure what you have in mind and to which extend can fullPage.js be the solution for you, but fullpage.js provides functions to turn it off and on such as `setAutoScrolling(false)`. You can check many of them [here in this demo](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/methods.html).

Comment: Probably using `scrollBar:true` would fit you better so the scroll bar will always be visible no matter if you use `autoScrolling` or not. As [in this example](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrollBar.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help; if `lethargy.js` does what it says it is exactly what I am looking for; but I can't get it to work– Would you take a look at it? I edited the question.

Comment: But when you look at my code again, it says "if lethargy.check(e) is false, don't do anything" and yet it logs the false. And still I don't understand why 1 and -1 get printed so often; the reason I want to use lethargy still is that I only want to trigger once per swipe. This is not happening here.

Comment: You'd better ask that questions in the letargy github issues or open a new topic here for that new question. I provided you with an answer to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, works perfectly without debouncing
https://codepen.io/JukJuchok/pen/zYJEybx

```
class SwipeDetector {
    deltaYHistoryLegth = 16;
    deltaYA1HistoryLegth = 16;
    deltaYA2HistoryLegth = 16;
    deltaYA3HistoryLegth = 16;

    previousPositiveDifference = 0;

    element;
    upCallback;
    downCallback;
    draw;

    deltaYHistory = new Array(this.deltaYHistoryLegth).fill(0);
    deltaYA1History = new Array(this.deltaYA1HistoryLegth).fill(0);
    deltaYA2History = new Array(this.deltaYA2HistoryLegth).fill(0);
    deltaYA3History = new Array(this.deltaYA3HistoryLegth).fill(0);
    deltaYA1 = 0;
    deltaYA2 = 0;
    deltaYA3 = 0;

    constructor(config) {
        this.element = config.element;
        this.upCallback = config.upCallback;
        this.downCallback = config.downCallback;
        this.draw = config?.draw;

        this.wheelListener = this.wheelListener.bind(this);

        this.element.addEventListener('wheel', this.wheelListener, { passive: false });

        this.storeZeros();
    }

    storeZeros() {
        this.storeDelataY(0)
        requestAnimationFrame(this.storeZeros.bind(this));
    }

    storeDelataY(deltaY) {
        this.deltaYHistory.push(deltaY);
        this.deltaYHistory.splice(0, 1);

        this.deltaYA1 = average(this.deltaYHistory);
        this.deltaYA1History.push(this.deltaYA1);
        this.deltaYA1History.splice(0, 1);

        this.deltaYA2 = average(this.deltaYA1History);
        this.deltaYA2History.push(this.deltaYA2);
        this.deltaYA2History.splice(0, 1);

        this.deltaYA3 = average(this.deltaYA2History);
        this.deltaYA3History.push(this.deltaYA3);
        this.deltaYA3History.splice(0, 1);

        const positiveDifference = this.calcPositiveDifference();

        if (this.draw) {
            this.draw([
                deltaY,
                this.deltaYA1,
                this.deltaYA2,
                this.deltaYA3,
                positiveDifference
            ]);
        }

        if (this.previousPositiveDifference === 0 && positiveDifference > 0) {
            this.upCallback();
        }
        if (this.previousPositiveDifference === 0 && positiveDifference < 0) {
            this.downCallback();
        }

        this.previousPositiveDifference = positiveDifference;
    }

    calcPositiveDifference() {
        const diff = (this.deltaYA2 - this.deltaYA3);
        if (this.deltaYA2 > 0) {
            return diff > 0 ? diff : 0;
        } else if (this.deltaYA2 < 0) {
            return diff < 0 ? diff : 0;
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    wheelListener(event) {
        this.storeDelataY(event.deltaY);
    }

    destroy() {
        this.element.removeEventListener('wheel', this.wheelListener)
    }
}

new SwipeDetector({
  element: window,
  upCallback: () => { console.log("swipe up") },
  downCallback: () => { console.log("swipe down") },
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).